# Update Google Play Developer API to Version3

Tags: android, jenkins, google-play-developer-api

I am building and pushing app to play store from Jenkins but it is breaking.I am getting following error.

- **This version of the Play Developer API is no longer available. 
  For more information see https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/03/changes-to-google-play-developer-api.html.**

How I can upgrade to version 3 for already exiting app.

Could some one please share the steps?

Answer (score 0):

Here are google's [instructions](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/03/changes-to-google-play-developer-api.html), which is not a lot.  Basically, where you build the client, ask for version='v3' of the api, such that the requests that are made are to `https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/` rather than v2 or v1.  So for python, something like

```
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        serviceName='androidpublisher', version='v3', http=http,
        cache_discovery=False)
```

This is a google example:

```
  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service, flags = sample_tools.init(
      argv,
      'androidpublisher',
      'v3',
      __doc__,
      __file__,
      parents=[argparser],
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher')
```